# subl -w on a directory

Tags: shell, sublimetext

The `-w` flag for `subl` will "wait for the files to be closed before returning" according to the docs. When I use this on a single file, it works fine, but if I open an entire directory, the process still waits after I close the Sublime Text window. Is it possible to use the `-w` flag with a directory (e.g., `subl -w .`)?